# Обновить datatable периодично

Tags: c#

Добрый день) Есть консольное приложение, которая берёт данные из таблицы SQL. Запускаем приложение, и нам надо будет добавить в `datatable` ещё одну запись. Как можно автоматический  обновить `datatable` периодично?

Создал `Thread`, и поставил таймер

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    Thread t1 = new Thread(one);
    t1.Start();


    TimerCallback time1 = new TimerCallback(one);
    Timer timeCB = new Timer(time1, null, 0, 300000);
}
```

Здесь я напишу что делает таймер. Незнаю что писать. Подскажите код, пожалуйста!

```
 public static void one(object state) {



 }
```

Comment: А cron не подходит ?

Comment: @M.Ivashchuk к сожалению нет(

Comment: что значит периодично в вашем случае: при каждом запуске программы? или программа работает в фоне и с определенным интервалом добавляет данные? Что должно в результате получиться?

Comment: @rdorn программа должна работать в фоне

Comment: таймеры чем не подходят?

Comment: @rdorn Программа работает в фоне и с определенным интервалом добавляет данные

Comment: @vitidev `System.Timers.Timer` подходят? Если да, то как я сделаю?

Comment: Таймеры для того и нужны чтобы периодично выполнять какие то операции. Все таймеры это делают, просто в некоторых реализована возможность кидать на форму, вызывать калбек сразу в UI и прочее. Вот  System.Timers.Timer как раз из таких. В основе всего лежит System.Threading.Timer - вызов калбека в пуле потоков без всяких синхронизаций и прочего.

Comment: @vitidev а `adapter.update` не подходят?

Comment: @vitidev и потом я создаю таймер, этот метод работает когда программа делается в фоне?

Comment: да, по таймеру переданный калбек будет периодично запускаться в одном из потоков пула, пока таймер не остановят/уничтожат в зависимости от выбранного тайера

Comment: @rdorn поможете?

Comment: а зачем вы в отдельном потоке колбэк для таймера руками запускаете, таймер сам справляется? и более важный вопрос - добавлять запись в таблицу умеете?

Comment: @rdorn *и более важный вопрос - добавлять запись в таблицу умеете?* да,умею . А можно в одном потоке? если да, то как? Подскажите пожалуйста!

Comment: вопрос был не в том,  зачем метод запускать в отдельном потоке, а в том зачем вы это делаете руками, когда таймер самостоятельно это умеет без посторонней помощи. Добавил решение, думаю вам подойдет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В .NET определены четыре стандартных класса таймеров, каждый со своими особенностями. В вашем случае, как правильно заметил в комментариях @vitidev, подойдет либо **[System.Threading.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)**, либо **[System.Timers.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)**. На EnSO нашел ссылку на сравнительную статью про таймеры: **[ответ на EnSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1416809/5796587)**, **[статья на английском](https://web.archive.org/web/20150329101415/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx)** (для не владеющих английским, в самом конце статьи есть сравнительная таблица таймеров). Также сравнение таймеров и их основное назначение приводятся в заметках к описаниям классов, но там это описание весьма скромное.

Я использовал `System.Timers.Timer`. Минимальный пример использования в коде ниже.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (Timer timer = new Timer())
    {
        timer.Interval = 2000;//интервал задается в миллисекундах
        timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
        timer.Start();
        //Ставим основной поток на ожидание, т.к. таймер исполняется в 
        //отдельном потоке и не препятствует завершению основного потока.
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    //тут пишем код, который должен выполняться по событию таймера.
    //в вашем случае это будет вызов метода записи в таблицу на сервере, 
    //либо собственно код этого метода.
    Console.WriteLine(e.SignalTime);
}
```

Более развернутые примеры для обоих типов таймеров содержаться в описании классов по ссылкам в начале ответа.

Разумеется, можно не просто ставить поток на ожидание, а выполнять другие полезные действия в основном потоке, пока таймер выполняет свою работу.

Есть и другой вариант решения задачи. Использовать цикл с выходом по счетчику или нажатию клавиши и `Thread.Sleep` для остановки основного и единственного потока на указанный интервал времени, но такое решение не смотря на простоту, мне не представляется хорошим. Когда задачи по таймеру выполняются в отдельных потоке мы можем выводить дополнительную информацию о ходе выполнения задач в консоль, управлять состоянием таймера и выполнять другие действия. В случае одного потока с паузами мы лишены свободы маневра, на время заморозки потока программа просто перестает реагировать на внешние раздражители и ее можно только принудительно закрыть.

Comment: спасибо за ответ! в `timer_Elapsed` что писать? Я не создаю запись руками. в sql сервере запись добавляется/изменяется/удаляется. я хочу просто обновить периодично `datatable`.

Comment: запись изменяется в сервере, а мне надо сделать только обновления `datatable`