# timer.Tick += delegate c# не срабатывает

Tags: c#, winforms, консоль, таймер, делегаты

Есть код написанный в Windows Forms:

```
DateTime TimeToWorkServerTemp;
DateTime ServerTemp = DateTime.Now;
 TimeToWorkServerTemp = new DateTime(ServerTemp.Year, ServerTemp.Month, ServerTemp.Day, ServerTemp.Hour, ServerTemp.Minute, 0);
var ServtempDel = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer { Interval = 1000, Enabled = true };
            ServtempDel.Tick += delegate
        {
            if (TimeToWorkServerTemp < DateTime.Now)
            { что то делается
                    TimeToWorkServerTemp = TimeToWorkServerTemp.AddMinutes(1);
                ServtempDel.Enabled = true;
            }
        };
```

Проблема в том что в Windows Form он спокойно отрабатывает, а если использовать в console то код не работает, подскажите в чем причина?

Comment: WF, WPF и т.д. создают контекст в котором и отрабатываются события таймеров. В консольном приложении Вы сами должны создавать контекст. Сталкивался с такой проблемой. К сожалению примеров не осталось, но вы можете найти информацию по этому вопросу в интернете свободно. [Похожий вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186084/how-do-you-add-a-timer-to-a-c-sharp-console-application)

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/535729/198316 изучайте, это как раз ваш консольный случай

Answer (score 2):

Причина в том что это System.Windows.**Forms**.Timer

Используйте `System.Threading.Timer` в консольных приложениях, да и в WinForms, тоже можно.
Или `System.Timers.Timer`, как подсказали в комментариях.

Comment: Внимание! System.Threading.Timer отрабатывает в другом потоке. см. межпоточное программирование `lock`, `Mutex` и т.д. Поправьте если я не прав.

Comment: А еще лучше - System. **Timers** .Timer.